# How to find the number of left coset of $H$ in symmetric group $S_7$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

It is given that $\sigma=\,(124)(3567)$, let $H$ be the subgroup of symmetric group $S_7$ generated by $\sigma$.

Find the number of left coset of $H$ in symmetric group $S_7$.

My attempt: I tried to find the order of $\sigma$, then we can use the Langrange Theorem to find the number of left coset of $H$ in symmetric group $S_7$. However, finding the order of $\sigma$ is very tedious, since $\sigma^{8}$ is still not equals to the identity permutation.

Could anyone give me a method or a hint?

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are two elements in a finite group that commute such that the subgroups they generate intersect trivially, then prove that the order of $ab$ is the l.c.m. of the orders of $a$ and $b$ respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Because the two cycles are disjoint, for every integer $k$
$$\sigma^k=(124)^k(3\ 5\ 6\ 7)^k.$$

Comment: thanks so much!!